# Italic characters' bottom cut off in textBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, tablelayoutpanel

I have a TableLayoutPanel with TableLayoutPanels as rows. Each of the inner tableLayoutPanels has two rows. In the second row is a `textBox` showing an URL in *italic* style. However the url is cutoff in its height, characters like 'g' miss some pixels and '_' isn't shown at all.

So I tried to change the textBox' height - no change - tried to change the row size of the inner tableLayoutPanel - no change - tried to change the inner tableLayoutPanel's size itself - no change...

Ironically there's another label with italic text in the same row, it is bound to the row's bottom per anchor, but even if I use an anchor on the textBox it's still cutoff.

The relevant textBox code:

```
textBox2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 9.75F, 
    System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, 
    ((byte)(0)));
textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 21);
textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(454, 23);
```

The inner tlp code:

```
tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new 
    System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 
    80F));
tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new 
    System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 
    27F));
tableLayoutPanel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(607, 44);
```

Is it somehow possible to display italic underscores: (originally 8OG8vit_-Wg)

[image: "8OG8vit_-Wg" cutoff]

**EDIT**: Placed the textbox on it's outer groupbox and also the main form.

```
System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
textBox2.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
textBox2.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.IBeam;
textBox2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 9.75F, 
    System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, 
    ((byte)(0)));
textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 290);
textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
textBox2.ReadOnly = true;
textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(454, 15);
textBox2.Text = "8OG8vit_-Wg";
textBox2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Coral;
groupBox1.Controls.Add(textBox2); // this.Controls.Add(textBox2);
```

Here are the results:[image: groupbox] and [image: mainform]

Comment: Try to set the BackColor to be sure the textbox effective size is actually large enough. AlsO: Do check all Padding and/or Margin values!

Comment: Nice tip, BackColor makes this easier. Sadly setting different textBox sizes shows that there is absolutetly no change. Moved the textBox up too, no visual difference. Looked through the elements, no Padding or Margin values have been set in the code. Are there default ones I need to mind?

Comment: _Are there default ones_ yes, usualy 3 pixels. does the same textbox still cut off when placed on the form directly?

Comment: @TaW Edited in two more examples

Comment: Ok, I can confirm. The problem seems to come from the combination of SingleLine and Border.None. You can make it multiline and the problem goes away.. Still weird, looks like a bug.

Comment: Awesome, works now, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't help but call this a **bug**.

The combination of `TextBox.Multiline = false` and `BorderStyle.None` seems to make winforms overdo the client size reductions and will cut off descenders and underlines.

The workaround is to give up on one of them; for the look you want simply make the `TextBox.Multiline = true` and all is as it should be..:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the following solution for this bug:

```
TextBox.MinimumSize = TextBox.Size;
```

(see https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22658664/Removing-BorderStyle-changes-height-of-text-box-and-bottom-of-letters-is-not-visible.html)

Comment: That makes it look worse for me haha