# RichTextBox Text displayed too Low - Descenders Cut Off

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a WinForm application with a RichTextBox that I am using instead of a TextBox because I wish to color code certain individual characters in the text.

When the text is displayed, it is displayed too low, such that the 'descenders' of characters are cut off. In the example below the text should display as **13, 14**. But it looks like **13. 14** as the descender of the comma character is cut off.

I have tried making the height of the RTB much greater and keeping the font size the same, but the descender is still cut off.

It seems to me that the line height is too small for the font size. But if I reduce the font size from 9.25 to 8, the same thing still happens; the character descenders are cut off.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546091/italic-characters-bottom-cut-off-in-textbox

Comment: Change the Font to `Segoe UI` (which is currently the default UI Font). Possibly, specify the target .NET and Windows System versions

Comment: I have found that changing the font from Microsoft San Serif to Segeo UI, or better still, Arial, eases the problem. The descenders are still cut off slightly, but not by as much as they were with Microsoft San Serif. I have also found that, by using the RichTextBox's SelectCharOffset, I can move the text down in the RTB by setting this property to a negative value, but unfortunately if I set it to a positive value it does not move the text up in the RTB.